# search values in dataframe and export to new column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a large datatset( about 1M rows) 
within this dataset, I want to find some values in one of columns (or multiple columns)

for example,

df contains

```
   col1 col2 col3
-------------------
      a   b    c
      d   e    f
      g   h    i
      j   k    l
      m   n    o
```

what i'm looking for is that searching each row and if the given value  exist, then output a "YES" in new col4

any help?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Scenario 1: search whole dataframe

We can use `DataFrame.eq` with `any` over the column axis, so for each row. This means, if the value `a` is in any of the column for a row, we get `True`:

```
df['indicator'] = df.eq('a').any(axis=1)

  col1 col2 col3  indicator
0    a    b    c       True
1    d    e    f      False
2    g    h    i      False
3    j    k    l      False
4    m    n    o      False
```

---

#### Scenario 2: for some columns:

We can apply the same logic for sub selection of columns, if we use `iloc`, to select the first two columns

```
df['indicator'] = df.iloc[:, :2].eq('d').any(axis=1)

  col1 col2 col3  indicator
0    a    b    c      False
1    d    e    f       True
2    g    h    i      False
3    j    k    l      False
4    m    n    o      False
```